# Parallel struture

Tags: parallelism

> "Studying abroad can be an educational experience for foreign
>   students. It may broaden their horizons. In addition, such an
>   experience can expand their knowledge of the world, as a result of
>   being exposed to different cultures and customs, which can be
>   interesting and enjoyable in many ways. In terms of job prospects,
>   they are more likely to be paid high salaries, ***quickly making them
>   more independent and able to own their own home."***

*Can these following concluded from bold part?*

In terms of job prospects, they are more likely to be paid high salaries, which quickly make them more independent and which makes them able to own their own home.

In terms of job prospects, they are more likely to be paid high salaries, quickly making them more independent and making them able to own their own home.

Answer (score 0):

The high salary

a. quickly makes them more independent, and

b. quickly makes them (more) able to own their own home.

It is not clear whether the second *more* is implied.

*to own one's own home* is a poor phrase because it uses the same word in different meanings. Why not say it helps them live in their own home, or simply to own a house?